# How Do I Change the onClick() Behavior of a Button?

Tags: java, android

I'm really not sure where to go with this question because I don't necessarily know how possible it is. I'm still somewhat new to Android Studio and coding overall, but I know enough to be dangerous (perhaps that's my problem - I may be thinking too grandiose for a beginner) but this is what I'm looking to do.

I have a single page app with several buttons. I'm creating an app that is essentially a score counter for an NFL game, and the section where my choices for scoring methods looks as follows:

[image: screenshot]

The above section is a Horizontal LinearLayout with 2 Nested LinearLayouts for the 4 scoring buttons on each side. The vertical toggle buttons are already set to change the text on the bottom button from Fieldgoal to Safety and vice-versa depending on the True/False of the toggle for each side.

```
teamOneToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                teamTwoToggleButton.setChecked(false);
                teamOneSafety.setText("SAFETY");
                teamTwoSafety.setText("FIELDGOAL");
            } else {
                teamTwoToggleButton.setChecked(true);
                teamTwoSafety.setText("SAFETY");
                teamOneSafety.setText("FIELDGOAL");
            }            }        });
```

I have that part figured out, but since a Safety scores as 2 points and a fieldgoal scores as 3 points, I need to be able to change the onClick behavior.

I was hoping that there was a Java function that would let me set a new onClick activity much like I can setText, setColor, setAlignment, set(whatever), but I can't find anything close.

I've also played around with trying to define a string based on a .getText() from the button itself, but my application crashes every time.

If anyone has any ideas my full code is here on my [Github](https://github.com/TheBaileyBrew/Football_ScoreKeeper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question you want to change the OnClickListener.

Currently you define it in your XML:

```
android:onClick="touchdownClickTeamOne" //This is not recommended practice, now you know.
```

You should do this in your Java code instead:

```
Button teamOneTouchDown = findViewById(R.id.team_one_off_td);
teamOneTouchDown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

Now you know how to redefine any button's OnClickListener.

---

> I'm not sure how to set it up in a way to programmatically do "this" if the button displays 'Safety' and do "that" if the button displays 'Fieldgoal'.

Currently you use this method:

```
public void fieldgoalClickTeamOne (View v) {
    scoreTeamOne = scoreTeamOne + 3;
    displayForTeamOne(scoreTeamOne);
}
```

We know the View `v` is a Button and that's Buttons are TextViews, so let's check the text:

```
public void fieldgoalClickTeamOne (View v) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) v; // Could cast to Button, makes no difference here
    if (textView.getText().toString().equals("SAFETY") {
        // Do this
    } else {
        // Do that
    }
}
```

---

**PS**  I'm happy to see a beginner following coding conventions, your code is very easy to read.  I have a few pointers.

First you should take a moment to learn the difference between `if`, `else if`, and `else`.  Your AdapterView should only have on `if` statement and many `else if`s.

Second you should take some time to learn about generic coding practices and/or reusability (this concept is a little tricky). Back to your AdapterViews, you only need one OnItemSelectedListener:

```
OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        final ImageView imageView;
        if (adapterView.getId() == R.id.teamOneSpinner) 
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.team_one_spinner_team_logo);
        else
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.team_two_spinner_team_logo);

        String s=((TextView)view).getText().toString();
        if(s.equals("Arizona Cardinals"))
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arizona_cardinals);
        else if(s.equals("Atlanta Falcons"))
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.atlanta_falcons));
        else if(s.equals("Baltimore Ravens")) 
            //etc, etc
```

Viola, one listener for multiple spinners.  Set it like so:

```
teamOneSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
teamTwoSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
```

See how much writing I saved you! Many of your methods are repetitive, you can remove 80% of your code with these techniques.

Comment: Yes, essentially I thought I needed to use the onClickListener, but I'm not sure how to set it up in a way to programmatically do "this" if the button displays 'Safety' and do "that" if the button displays 'Fieldgoal'.  Especially since my method to count the score happens outside of the main onCreate.

Comment: Ahh, well, I preempted you a little but I used the Spinners as an example.  I'll add an example to your comment in a moment.

Comment: I added another blurb, hope that helps! If it does please upvote the anver and accept it as the solution.

Comment: That makes so much sense!  Thank you for the overall feedback, I truly appreciate it - I want to overall become more efficient in my code.

Comment: Sam, I started looking through what you posted above, and it makes alot of sense, but after I started bringing your **PS** into my .java file to update the AdapterView like you suggested, I get an error here:
`final ImageView imageView;`
`if (parent.getId() == R.id.teamOneSpinner)`

It tells me:  cannot resolve symbol "parent" -- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry about that. You aren't doing anything wrong, I wrote the wrong variable name. Change `parent` to `adapterView`.